# How to allocate the split value of a variable into 2 categories of another variable

Tags: r, split, tidyverse, categorical-data, group

I am trying to code offenders into race categories to clean up a criminal justice database.
One of the race categories is "equal number of blacks and whites". I've been asked to take the number of offenders (variable V4248), split its value and allocate 1/2 the value to "whites" and 1/2 the value to "blacks". Codingwise, I am not sure how to do this. This is where Im at so far:

1. I created the race variable
2. I created a variable to split the value (but this is where I'm not sure how to code it)
3. I combine the two variables above.

```
    ncvs11 <- ncvs10 %>% 
    mutate(total_ethnic = case_when(off_race_hisp == 1 | multi_race_ethnic == 1 ~ 1, #White
                                    off_race_hisp == 2 | multi_race_ethnic == 2 ~ 2, #Black
                                    multi_race_ethnic == 3 ~ 3,
                                    off_race_hisp == 4 | multi_race_ethnic == 4 ~ 4 #Hispanic
                                    )) %>%
    
    mutate(offsplit = case_when(total_ethnic == 3 ~ V4248/2) %>%
             #WHAT DO I DO HERE?
             
    mutate(final_ethnic = case_when(total_ethnic == 1 | total_ethnic == 2 | 
                                      total_ethnic == 4 ~ total_ethnic,
                                    total_ethnic == 3 ~ offsplit))
```

Thanks,

Comment: Could you share `dput(ncvs11)` here so we can reproduce your data

Comment: @TomHoel How do I share here? I don't see a place to upload the csv file.